# Role of rank condition in identification of 2SLS - matrix algebra

Tags: regression, linear, linear-algebra, 2sls

I could write down all the steps for identification of the 2SLS estimator but my question is really a matrix algebra question which is required in the last step for finding out what the beta vector is identified by.

Let A be k x k. Let B be L x K and C be L x L. C is assumed nonsingular. C is also symmetric. Let D be the inverse of C. 
Identification requires that A is nonsingular. A is given by

A=B'DB.

I read the statement in Wooldridge(2002, pg. 94) that A is nonsingular (i.e. has rank K)  if and only if B has rank K.

I am unable to prove this statement. In a google search I tried to look at properties of ranks of matrices and rank of the product of matrices but I am unable to find a usable theorem.

Could someone help me with this?

Thank you!